# Authentication Failed when i test my Rest API in JMeter

Tags: web-services, jmeter

I have been asked to test my Rest API in JMeter and configured my service details in HTTP Request tab in JMeter and unfortunately i am seeing Authentication failed error even though it displays correct information in Request tab.

[image]

[image]

Here is my Header Manager section as below...

[image]

This is my request and using POST method for this.

[image]

Can you pls help in getting this fixed...

Comment: Which method you are using GET or POST? Please post the HTTP request snapshot.

Comment: Hi Naveen, I have added request image in the post.Thanks,

Comment: Thanks @Ram Karlapudi. Couple sanity things. Make sure you are using valid JSON. You can validate it using `jsonlint` online tool. Also, every time token will expire. You need to extract the token from the first request and pass it in the subsequent request. Let me know if you need any help. :)

Comment: Thanks for quick reply Naveen. Yes JSON is correct Naveen. I need a help in extracting the token from request..Can you help me ..

Comment: Yes Sure. Let me check to create a chat.

Comment: Please join this room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143423/jmeter

Comment: sure naveen....

Comment: Unfortunately...my client is blocking this chat and i am getting Access denied message:(

Comment: Have you clicked on above chat.stackoverflow.com link? If your network is blocking, then you can contact me in FB.

Comment: i sent a friend request in FB Naveen.. My company is blocking this site..

Answer (score 0):

you have to implement correct correlation.
Authentication must be executed every time.
The authorization token is a random value that you get from previous authentication.
You have to extract it (maybe with a regular expression) and use it in the HTTP operation.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way of testing resources protected by [Basic HTTP Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) is using [HTTP Authorization Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager).

1. Add HTTP Authorization Manager to your test plan
2. Provide Base URL and credentials (plain text)

That's it, you don't need to add Authorization header manually, JMeter will automatically generate it, check out [How to Use HTTP Basic Authentication in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-http-basic-authentication-jmeter) article for more details if required.